# Нахождение атрибута и выделение его параметров через анализатор Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

Требуется подчеркнуть строку, содержащую русские символы и вывести информацию в output как warning.

Написал расширение для анализатора Roslyn. Но почему-то если я вписываю русский текст в параметрах для атрибута метода, то информация корректно выводится и нужное место подчёркивается. Вот код:

1) Происходит инициализация:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
      {
         context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeRussianSymbols, SymbolKind.Parameter);
      }
```

2) Метод выше дёргает `AnalyzeRussianSymbols`:

```
public void AnalyzeRussianSymbols(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
      {
         CompilationUnitSyntax root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)context.Symbol.Locations[0].SourceTree.GetRoot();

         AttributeListVirtualizationVisitor attributeArgument = new AttributeListVirtualizationVisitor();
         attributeArgument.Visit(root);

         CheckAttributes(attributeArgument, context);
      }
```

3) И вот тут я проверяю атрибуты:

```
private void CheckAttributes(AttributeListVirtualizationVisitor attributeArgument, SymbolAnalysisContext context)
      {
         foreach (AttributeArgumentListSyntax attributes in attributeArgument.AttributeArgumentsList)
         {
            foreach (AttributeArgumentSyntax attr in attributes.Arguments)
            {
               SyntaxKind syntaxKind = attr.Expression?.Kind() ?? SyntaxKind.None;
               if(syntaxKind == SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression && Regex.IsMatch(attr.NormalizeWhitespace().Expression.ToString(), "[а-яА-ЯёЁ]"))
               {
                  Diagnostic diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, attr.Expression.GetLocation(), attr.NormalizeWhitespace().Expression);
                  context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
               }
            }
         }

      }
```

Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как видно по картинке, расширение для атрибутов класса почему-то не работает. Хотя под дебагом в условие заходит.

Подскажите как быть?

Comment: Как минимум показать код, к которому относится этот вопрос.

Comment: @NewView готово!

Comment: Возможно либо атрибуты `AttributeListVirtualizationVisitor` у класса не те, либо `context.Symbol.Locations[0].SourceTree.GetRoot()` начинает не с наймспейса а изнутри класса, в дебагер надо глянуть, что там.

Comment: @NewView `GetRoot()` начинает с using

Comment: Ну так а если идти пошагово? После заполнения атрибутов переменной root? там то оно есть? И как выглядит? Так же как и 'рабочий' атрибут?

Comment: @NewView `attributeArgument` заполняется также как рабочий вариант после метода `Visit()`

Comment: Попробуйте класс назвать по английский :) может он не понимает что `Вася` это класс и к нему следует чего то там применять.. Все свойства атрибута и элемента сравните, особенно всякие boolean значения.

Comment: @NewView неплохое предположение) Но не в этом дело. сейчас попробовал атрибуты у свойств, у них тоже не подчёркивается. Буду анализировать. Я ещё вот этим пользуюсь, но там примерно для всех атрибутов одинаково: http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/